# How to run all shell scripts inside a directory, calling those scripts in other shell script file

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I'm writing a shell script where I need to call another shell script inside that.

Basically, I'm trying to call all shell scripts from the directory $d running `bash "$d"/*.sh`, but when I do that the looping never ends and it keeps calling all scripts.

```
for d in "$dir"/*/ ; do
    echo " diretorio $d"
    cd $d
    for f in * ; do
        if [[ $f == *.sh ]]; then    
            if [[ $d == "tools/" ]]; then
                echo "$d"
            else
                bash "$d"/*.sh
            fi
        else
            if [[ $f == *.yaml ]]; then   
                python3 -c 'import yaml, sys; print(yaml.safe_load(sys.stdin))' < $f
            fi
        fi
    done
    cd ..
done
```

Comment: Is *this* script inside that directory structure?

Comment: @JeffSchaller yes

Comment: Perhaps the solution is as simple as checking for its own filename, so that it doesn't re-execute itself, then?

Comment: @JeffSchaller But in this case, I don't know the filename, I just know there is a .sh file inside the directory

Comment: You're saying that this script is inside the directory, but you don't know what its filename is?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Yes, because in the future I want to add a new directory and I expect this script could execute the script inside the new directory.